# Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'firebase-admin' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update a Firebase Cloud Function that I havent touched for a year. Deployment went without issues back then.

Here is my setup: I have a root index.ts file, and functions are organized into folders.
root index.ts

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin";

// Initialize Firebase Admin
initializeApp();

export {notifyNewMessages} from "./notify_new_messages";
export {onUpdateUsers, onUpdateUserRatings} from "./on_update/index";
export {onUninstall} from "./on_uninstall/index";
```

and notifyNewMessages file starts like this

```
import {FirebaseError, firestore, messaging} from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import i18n from "./localization";
import {Ask, Device, User} from "./models";

import DocumentSnapshot = firestore.DocumentSnapshot;

const fcm: messaging.Messaging = messaging();
```

Could this separated root file cause this problem?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using ES Modules, and as firebase has moved to modular SDK namespace versions require some modifications so try the following:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const app: admin.app.App = admin.initializeApp();
```

You can go through this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10) for other changes to be made.

Comment: PS I solved this issue, but had to completely delete the old function, and also do a firebase init into a new folder to sync the latest Firebase settings... Eg the new Firebase environment is not for Node 16...